# How to communicate with switch EKI-1526 and electric meter using c#

Tags: c#

I want to create a project in which I have a switch device EKI-1526 and Electric Meter ELSter AS3500 and i want to develop application using c# and try to start communication with meter through switch serially. I have idea about serial class and DataReceived handler. But don't know exactly from where I can start. Anyone have suggestion are welcome.

Hope for best.

Comment: Find the technical manual for that device, look for the section that contains the protocol and implement it. Why do you want to communicate with the EKI directly? isn't the whole point of that thing, that the software that comes with it creates virtual COM ports so that you **don't** have to bother with that yourself?

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer I do it with virtual COM, now I want to read the data from actual device , in my case it's ELSter meter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use serial port for communication. Maybe you need an rs232 to rs485 converter.

Comment: How can I test that the wire mapping is fine and I received the signal and now ready to code.

Comment: You can plug a serial to rj45 to the switch and with some terminal emulator application on the other end(serial end) send some dummy data.

Comment: I use the software SerialMON and connect usb with RS 485 converter and join the wires on other sides to check it return back the signal and the test was pass, but when I connect the wires with meter there is no signal, may be this is because the meter cannot understand when can I send to it. Any idea